# Is there a simpler way to rewrite this binomial chain?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider some binomial chain that looks like this:

$$\binom{N}{k_1}\binom{N-k_1}{k_2}\binom{N-k_1-k_2}{k_3}\binom{N-k_1-k_2-k_3}{k_4} \cdots \binom{N-k_1-k_2-\cdots -k_{t-1}}{k_t}$$

Where all variables $N$ and $k_1$ through $k_t$ are known positive integers.

Is there some simple way to compress this?

Comment: Yes, google "Multinomial coefficient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the sum of the $k_i$ is $N$, which it usually is, your expression simplifies to
$$\frac{N!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_t!}.$$

Comment: I'd have to see the real problem. But I would be surprised if we had divisibility problems in the "simplified" version but not in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $N=k_1+ k_2+ k_3+ \cdots + k_t$ then what you have is a *multinomial coefficient*:

$${N\choose k_1, k_2, k_3, \ldots, k_t} = \frac{N!}{k_1!\,k_2!\,k_3!\cdots k_t!}$$